# how to stop modification and changes in client side source file in developer tool?

Tags: javascript, client-side

I am using angular in i can easily add some javascript code and modify the program. Is there any way to stop modification in source file?

[image]

Comment: No. Client-side code can always be changed / modified by the user.

Comment: you can't do this

Comment: But you can minify and compress your code using grunt/gulp and user cannot understand your code, cant edit your code

Comment: ok i'll try minify code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) and [Minify](https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify) methods to make changes difficult, but never stop them.

Answer (score 0):

Its Developer Feature provided in browser to do client side modification for testing purposes.

you dont worry it wont modify your source code anyhow.. its just for some time till the page getting reloaded..

because your code will located in server which secure enough. so its not possible to edit from client side tool like `Developer console`

But if you can prevent user to get into `Developer tools` .

user following `ctrl+shift+i` or `F12` or `Right Click->inspect Element` way to get into it.

you can still disable those prevent user to enter into Dev tools.

[for more info](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DeveloperToolsDisabled) how to disable dev tools